# Can a remotely stored ASP app access a networked local machine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, uniobjects

I'm about to being developing an application that will connect to a Unix machine on a network (via internal IP). The machines that will be running this application already have access to connect to the Unix machine.

If I develop an ASP.NET MVC Web App running on an external IIS instance, will the web app be able to connect to a private local machine? I realise the IIS server won't (as it's private), but there will be locally executed code. Is this going to be able to access the machine? If not, I will have to resort to Windows desktop app.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 2 app's

Comment: The purpose is to allow editing of UniVerse databases that exist on a networked server inside a private network - where the actual web app resides on an external host. (So that it's not a specific installation for one company)

Comment: You can't connect to the database directly from the other server through some sort of direct connection method or api?

Comment: No, it's behind a firewall. I don't wish for the remote server to necessarily be able to see the data. That's really the reason for my question. I'd like the flexibility of having the app be remotely hosted on IIS but still be able to provide the user with access to their own UniVerse databases via a local connection (to which the remote app doesn't have access). I am just interested in the feasibility of this, otherwise a locally installed desktop app would be the second option, providing secure access but losing some of the flexibility of the web app.

Comment: How is a user supposed to have db access when the app doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VPN connection from an external server to the private network. Virtual hosting hasn't this feature, so you must use virtual machine.

A firewall software allows you to create VPN server usually, and any version of Windows allows you to establish a VPN connection to the server.

With a help of VPN connection your virtual machine can get ф private IP-address, and can access private network resources.